# Using primefaces with jsf 2.0 in Eclipse

Tags: jar

What are the requriements to work with prime faces in jsf 2.0 Ide eclipse...

Any jar files are necessary?

Please kindly give me solution....

Thanks 
             vamsy krishna

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the folowing steps:

1. Download latest release of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (at the moment of writing post - Juno release);
2. Download latest stable release of PrimeFaces library (at the moment of writing post - 3.4);
3. Create new Dynamic Web application with using JSF 2.0 or 2.1;
4. After you create new JSF project, just put your primefaces-x.y.jar archive into folder /WEB-INF/lib of your project. I used "Import" menu command.

P.S. Maybe I did something wrong, but adding primefaces-x.y.jar as external jar file in "build path" options did not help me. 
Sory for late answer, but maybe it will be helpful for someone else. I found this post while finding answers for same question.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need eclipse 3.6 or later..
there is only one jar file for primefaces..
the latest stable jar can be downloaded and added to your "build path" or to "lib" directory.